# What Exception to raise when database operation is unsuccessful?

Tags: python-3.x, database, exception

### The Exception hierarchy

[The class hierarchy for built-in exceptions](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html)

#### How to know what exception must be raised if a database operation is not completed?

### Generic Exception

```
insert = collection.insert_one(foo)
if insert.acknowledged:
    logger.info(f'data saved: {foo}')
else:
    raise Exception('data not saved')
```

### Specific Exception

Is there any Built-in Exception that is broadly used and accepted under this scenario?

Answer (score 0):

It will depend on the reason why the operation was not successful.
Usually projects declare a base class and use a convention of statusCodes/messages.

Using Exception is perfectly acceptable.But in a medium/large code base, it would be worth it to have some subclasses of Exception to better communicate.

Answer (score 0):

You could model your exceptions on the ones used by the built-in `sqlite3` module, or even use them directly:  https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html#exceptions

Comment: That's helpful! I guess that other databases  modules, like postgres or mongo, come with their own exceptions.